# Prevent $.ajax from encoding forward slashes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an API I am working with, and they expect a certain parameter to be `/on/` or `/off/`. If I use the standard jQuery `$.ajax` it encodes to `%2Fon%2F` which fails on the API. Since I don't have access to the API to make it decode, how can I prevent jQuery from encoding the slashes?

The API uses `GET`, and here is a sample call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api.website.com",
    data: {id: id, stuff: stuff, device: device},
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
})
```

Comment: Show your code. What does the original data look like? How are you sending it? Is it a POST or a GET?

Comment: @MattBurland, updated, though the sample code is the simplest ajax call I can imagine, so I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: It is necessary - because you are using GET. That means the parameters are inserted into the query string of the URL and *must* be encoded. I'm not sure how it's possible that your API could expect you to pass unencoded characters in the url. Are you sure that the API doesn't either a) decode them anyway or b) expect a POST rather than a GET?

Comment: @MattBurland yes I am 100% sure. The people who made the API made it against standards, in their example calls they are using XMLHttprequest with `xmlhttp.open("GET", "api.website.com?id="+id+"&stuff=/off/&device="+device, false)`

Comment: So why not do it the same way they do it? Or even just build the url via string manipulation instead of passing `data` to `$.ajax`?

Comment: @MattBurland because for my own code, `$.ajax` is cleaner to read and use. But if it doesn't support a way to not encode it I'll have to build the direct url I guess.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's kind of ugly. On the bright side, if it's only the `stuff` part of the query string you could append that to the `url` and still pass the rest of the data in `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will try to encode the query string because *that's what you are supposed to do*. So those `/` characters are going to get encoded. The only way around it is to build the query string yourself appended to the `url`. Luckily, or maybe not, you only actually need to do that for the parameters that are going to have the offending characters (`stuff` in your example):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.website.com?stuff=" + stuff,
    data: {id: id, device: device},
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
})
```

Comment: Best of a bad situation, thanks. Going to have a word with the people in charge of the API, see if I can't get them to update it.

Comment: @sharf I am facing the same issue.. did u find solution in all these years?